# Where can I edit the CSS default snippets file of VSCode?

Tags: css, file, visual-studio-code, default, code-snippets

I found `php.code-snippets` in `C: \Users \yourname \AppData \Local \Programs \Microsoft VS Code\snippets` but where is the CSS file?

I want to modify my snippets because vscode doesn't add the semicolon at the end of the line, it's a little bit annoying.

Thank you.

Comment: do you mean the Emmet commands, if so not a good idea to edit them because with an update of VSC you loose the edits, but Emmet adds `;` for me, which snippet do you mean

Comment: When I types some css code like display: `flex` it will rend `display: flex` whitout semicolon

Comment: you have to type `disTABflTAB`